# Escape some elements in xml when convert to java object use XStream

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xstream

I want to convert xml file to java object and escape some elements in xml.

I use XStream library to serialize objects to XML and back again.

This is my code:

```
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.processAnnotations(Articles.class);    

    try {
    InputStream in = XmlUtil.openURLConnection(url, 3).getInputStream();

    Articles articles = (Articles)xstream.fromXML(in);

    logger.info("Timestamp: " + articles.getTIMESTAMP());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warning("IOException: " + e);
    }
```

This is my "Articles" class:

```
@XStreamAlias("ARTICLES")
public class Articles implements Serializable
{
@XStreamAlias("TIMESTAMP")
private String TIMESTAMP;

public String getTIMESTAMP() {
    return TIMESTAMP;
}

public void setTIMESTAMP(String timestamp) {
    TIMESTAMP = timestamp;
}
}
```

I want from all xml only some elements like "TIMESTAMP".

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you also give an example XML file so I can see what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution. It's simple use the xstream.ignoreUnknownElements() method.